# Explain why the code compiles successfully

Tags: c, comments, c-preprocessor

Usually, if a `*/`*(block comment closing)* is present in the code without a `/*`*(block comment opening)*, the compiler produces an error.

However, why does the compiler ***NOT*** produce an error in the following case?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    #ifdef abcd
    printf("what ever it is");
    #endif */   --> the problem with this stray '*/' after #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand what you're asking here...

Comment: Please revise your question, we don't really understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I've just compiled the code you provide with gcc 4.6.x without any flags and got a warning

```
warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
```

So preprocessor at first remove all comments and then just skip all the data at the line of #endif. So i don't know is it a bug or a feature, but i got the warning about it, so the developers know about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Educated guess: this is strictly a bug in the preprocessor, and what it does is ignore everything after an `#endif`, which can't be followed by anything anyways.

Comment: +1 Yeap. You're right. Any documentation anywhere about this bug? I had no idea such a bug existed. What would be the implications of such a bug? Will the generated .obj file have whatever is after the `#endif`?

Comment: The original question was pretty hard to understand until it was edited.  I didn't even realise the question was why it DID compile!

Answer (score 0):

If i'm getting the question you had:

```
/*
#ifdef abcd
printf("what ever it is");
#endif */
```

You removed the "/*" from the beginning and the code doesn't compile ?

This is good because the code should not compile. you have a comment closer without the beginning.

what you could do is replace the "*/" with "//*/":

```
/*
#ifdef abcd
printf("what ever it is");
#endif //*/
```

That's way you can remove the "/*" from the beginning without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#endif */
```

That's the end of a block comment, where is the block comment opening?

```
/*
```

Comment: Maybe he wants to know , WHY even if there is no comment opening ... the code compiles fine...

Answer (score 0):

First, since `*/` is not part a comment, it is ignored in translation phase 3, described in C 2011 (n1570) 5.1.1.2 1 3.; the characters simply pass through unchanged.

Thus, in phase 4 (executing preprocessor directives), the compiler sees `#endif */`. Per C 2011 (n1570) 6.10 1, the proper syntax for an `#endif` directive is:

```
# endif new-line
```

That is, it consists of three preprocessing tokens, `#`, `endif`, and a new-line character, with spaces and tabs allowed between the tokens. So `#endif */` is not proper syntax.

5.1.1.3 requires a conforming implementation to produce a diagnostic message if the source violates a syntax rule. So, if a compiler does not produce a warning or error message in this case, it is not conforming.

Some compilers operate by default in a mode that does not conform to the C standard. Your compiler might have switches to change this, such as GCC’s `-std=c99` switch. If your compiler does not issue a warning or error message when in a conforming mode, then it is a bug.